# QEMU/KVM nic properties

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nic, qemu

1) What's the use of the `addr` value when specifying a new network interface on `QEMU/KVM` ?

Example: `qemu -hda deb.img -net nic,addr=192.168.1.10`

2) Is there a way to specify directly the IP address of a network interface ?

(Directly means at the moment we launch the guest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-net nic` is a deprecated syntax though it still works; -netdev replaced it. The `addr` parameter to `-net nic` is the PCI bus address, not the network address.

No, you can't tell the guest OS what IP to assign itself from the command line. You can use dhcp or slaac to notifying the guest of its network config.

You will also want to set appropriate nft or iptables and ebtables rules to prevent guest OSes from doing anything nefarious.